# Why am I getting an uninitialized value warning when reading two lines at a time?

Tags: perl, filehandle

I am trying to read two lines at a time with a `while` loop but am getting this error:

```
line    1
line    2
line    3
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ....
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ....
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ....
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;

my $count = 1;
while ( my $two_lines = <DATA> . <DATA> ) {
    print $two_lines;
}


__DATA__
line    1
line    2
line    3
```

Comment: perl v5.20, maybe that is the reason. Is there anyway to fix this error?

Comment: Output is good but giving this error message.

Comment: Instead of reading to the end of file, you are looping as long as the concatination returns "something true".  The core of your problem is that you are attempting to read (and use for concatination) lines 4, 5 & 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The readline operator `<HANDLE>` returns undef when reading from an exhausted filehandle (in scalar handle). So the first warning comes in the 2nd iteration of the `while` loop when you read the (missing) 4th line from `DATA`.
The next two warnings come from the 3rd iteration, when you call `<DATA>` twice on an exhausted filehandle.

You can fix this by using an expression that will not be `undef`. Since you're using perl >=v5.16, you can use

```
while (my $line = (<DATA> // '') . (<DATA> // '')) { ...
```

Comment: I tried same code on both version. Actually, the error is in v5.21 (also mentioned by @toolic in comment) and not in v5.16. This helped me to fix the warnings in v5.21 but I am not able to understand what is going on here in the code. Could you explain little bit more?

Comment: What happens when there are three lines of text after the `__DATA__` token in your program and you call `<DATA>` six times? The first three times it returns the three lines of text, the next three times it returns `undef`. When you perform most binary operations and one of the operands is `undef`, and warnings are enabled, you get a `Use of uninitialized value ...` warning message.

Comment: This will fail to work if the last line contains nothing but `0` (no separator) and is an odd line.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really an error, its just a warning.  You should get 2 warnings on even line number files, and 3 warnings on odd numbered files.  When it comes through the while expression the first time, it reads from  the first time fine, then when it reads the second time, the filehandle is empty, and it prints the warning.  Because it returned something the first time, it will execute the contents of the while loop.  the last time, it will evaluate the  filestream twice, get nothing and abort the loop, but warn both times it tries to concaticate the empty reads.  If you need a while loop i would do

```
while ( my $first_lines = <DATA> ) {
    if (my $second_line = <DATA> ){
         print $first_lines . $second_line;
    }else{
        print $first_lines
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it really is an error. Warnings can indicate errors just as much as exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

`readline` aka `<$fh>` returns undef to signal the end of the file (or an error). You're not checking for that. Fix:

```
while (1) {
   defined( my $line1 = <DATA> )
      or last;
   defined( my $line2 = <DATA> )
      or die("Premature end of file\n");

   print($line1 . $line2);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, here is the error: `Value of <HANDLE> construct can be "0"; test with defined()`

Comment: Hum, didn't know they added that warning. I've added a workaround though it's not really needed.

Answer (score 0):

What you may not be aware of is that

```
while ( my $line = <DATA> ){ ... }
```

is short for

```
while ( defined( my $line = <DATA> ) ){ ... }
```

That transformation only occurs for simple constructs like that.

If it didn't check for `defined`ness then it could skip the last line if it contained nothing but `0`.
( the other lines are guaranteed to have a line separator as well, so they would continue to work correctly. )

---

A way to get it to work similarly for one or two lines at a time is:

```
# take advantage of the built-in transformation
while ( my $two_lines = <DATA> ) {
  $two_lines .= <DATA> // '';

  ... # your code here
}
```